# How do I sort through this array in the way I want?

Tags: ruby

Say I have an array like this:

```
[["bham", "php"],
 ["auburn", "php"],
 ["bham", "php"],
 ["phoenix", "php"],
 ["phoenix", "php"],
 ["phoenix", "php"],
 ["phoenix", "php"],
 ["phoenix", "php"],
 ["mobile", "php"],
 ["phoenix", "php"],
 ["phoenix", "php"],
 ["phoenix", "php"],
 ["phoenix", "php"],
 ["phoenix", "php"],
 ["phoenix", "php"],
 ["phoenix", "php"],
 ["phoenix", "php"],
 ["phoenix", "php"],
 ["phoenix", "php"],
 ["tucson", "php"],
 ["tucson", "php"],
 ["phoenix", "php"],
 ["phoenix", "php"],
 ["phoenix", "php"]]
```

I would like to do a few things:

1. Count the number of arrays that have `php` as the 2nd element - so `["bham", "php"] would count as 1.
2. Count the number of times each of the first elements appear throughout the list. i.e. how many times does `bham` appear in the entire array, and how many times does `auburn` appear, etc. So basically, I want to cycle through this 2D array and for the first element of each child, I want to check to see if I have already recorded this string - if I have then I increment the value recorded and if I have not then I create a new entry for this new string.

This particular array is relatively trivial and can be done visually relatively easily, but assume that I will have an array with hundreds/thousands of elements.

It is also safe to assume that both elements of each child array will always be a single word - so it should be relatively easy to keep track of.

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Count is easy:

```
a.count{|x| x[1] == 'php'}
#=> 24
```

And for grouping how about group_by:

```
a.group_by{|x| x[0]}.map{|k,v| [k,v.size]}
#=> [["bham", 2], ["auburn", 1], ["phoenix", 18], ["mobile", 1], ["tucson", 2]]
```

Comment: Ah I thought that `size` took a block and was going to use that in my answer but then realized it didn't, but I guess only `count` does and that's what I was thinking of. +1

Comment: I love this...I have one question though. Can you explain the `group_by`. As in, why do you group them first (I get that you grouped them by the first element) - if you didn't group them would the map function still work? Then can you explain what the `map` does. More specifically, how does `v.size` know to increment? I know that the `v` local variable maps to the 2nd element in the array from the block. I am just curious about the `v.size` with respect to doing exactly what I want it to do.

Comment: Try it for yourself in irb: `a.group_by{|x| x[0]}` - it returns a hash with the grouped_by values as the keys and arrays of matches as the values. v.size is just Array#size applied to the matches arrays.

Comment: I did do it in irb first, and saw the output, and I read the definition in the Ruby docs - but I missed the hashrocket that indicate the hash. I thought I was just seeing an array of arrays like the input. That's why I was a bit confused with how the `map` method was producing that result. But now that I see the right output, it makes total sense. Ok..Thanks much meng!

Answer (score 2):

> Count the number of arrays that have php as the 2nd element

[`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to get just the last elements, then [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) only the ones we care about, and get the size:

```
array.map(&:last).select { |s| s == 'php' }.size
#=> 24
```

---

> Count the number of times each of the first elements appear throughout the list

[`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to get just the first elements, then iterate over it building a hash to store the counts:

```
array.map(&:first).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |s, h| h[s] += 1 }
#=> {"bham"=>2, "auburn"=>1, "phoenix"=>18, "mobile"=>1, "tucson"=>2}
```

Comment: Thanks for this...I prefer pguardiario's solution though - appears more elegant. But I upvoted yours for detail and effort. I really appreciate you taking the time :)